# ¿Cómo colocar imagenes en un select?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap

El problema debe estar en que el estilo de Bootstrap que estoy usando no permite que se muestre la imagen, pues he logrado que las imágenes se muestren creando un pequeño código en un bloc de notas:

```
<html>
<body>

<select id='cbxIdColorINS' runat='server'  size="2">
    <option style="background-image:url(C:/SISTEMA/WebMAINMENU/Images/Banderas/0.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat; padding-left:20px;">gggggggggg</option>
    <option style="background-image:url(C:/SISTEMA/WebMAINMENU/Images/Banderas/1.png); 
        background-repeat:no-repeat; padding-left:20px;">gggggggggg</option>
    <option style="background-image:url(C:/SISTEMA/WebMAINMENU/Images/Banderas/2.png); 
        background-repeat:no-repeat; padding-left:20px;">gggggggggg</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo con Asp.Net tienes que tener todos esos datos en un objeto.
También te recomiendo que tengas tus imagenes dentro de una carpeta, por ejemplo Content/Images/Banderas/

Por ejemplo en tu controlador tienes que tener algo como esto.

```
ViewBag = ['0.png', '1.png' , '2.png'];
```

Luego en tu vista hace algo como esto

```
<select>
@foreach(var element in ViewBag){
     <option style="background-image:url('~/Content/Images/Banderas/' + element); background- 
      repeat:no-repeat; padding-left:20px;">gggggggggg</option>   
}
</select>
```